# How to mount Galaxy S3 on a mountain bike

Tags: mountain-bike, smartphone-mount

I want to mount my Galaxy S III on my mountain bike. I already use a case that suites me well, so I don't want to go for another case. What I'm looking for is a mounting system which will mount my phone with it's case on to my bike securely and by that I mean really secure, because I ride pretty rough terrain regularly. I really like Rokform, but it requires to switch to their case plus it's very expensive (around $100 for the whole solution), I'm planning to spend not more than $30 on this. So to put it short I'm looking for a universal solution, that can securely house and mount Galaxy S III in it's case on a mountain bike.

Comment: If this question was reworded to be more generally geared toward universal bike mounts, I'd vote to reopen.

Comment: I reworded it, can someone please reopen?

Comment: Good question. I'm looking for an s3 mount for a road bike.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to go with something purpose made for that specific model of phone to get a secure mount on the bike. I'm not aware of any universal phone mount options that are worth anything, however you can [browse Wally World](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Bracketron-Waterproof-Case-with-Bike-Mount/15860629?findingMethod=rr) if you feel like wagering $20 one yourself. There are few different brands, but the Bracketron universal mount has sealed/waterproof zippers whereas the Arkon does not. I *can* tell you from personal experience that the Arkon universal car mount I have has had to be Frankensteined back into working condition about 4 different times over the last several years, so I don't have a lot of faith in their products.